# Why is my jQuery.post() ajax failing when I return one View but does not fail when i return another?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to write a straightforward comment poster. I have this code in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ViewResult Comments(MemberData md, long EntryId, string Comment, long LastId = 0)
    {
        bool isModerated = true;
        bool isLoggedIn = GenesisRepository.IsNotGuest(md.MemberGUID);
        bool isCommentAllowed = GenesisRepository.IsPermissionAssigned(md.MemberGUID, "Comments", "Create");

        // Moderate comment?
        if (moderateGuestComments == false && isLoggedIn == false) isModerated = false;
        if (moderateMemberComments == false && isLoggedIn) isModerated = false;

        long memberId = (from m in GenesisRepository.Member
                         where m.MemberGUID == md.MemberGUID
                         select m.MemberID)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

        if (
            EntryId > 0 
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comment) 
            && memberId > 0
            && isCommentAllowed)
        {
            Comments comment = new Comments { 
                Comment = Comment,
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                isActive = isModerated ? false : true,
                MemberID = memberId,
                StreamEntryID = EntryId,
            };
            if (GenesisRepository.SaveComment(comment))
            {
                List<Comments> comments = new List<Comments>();
                comments = (from c in GenesisRepository.Comments
                            where c.StreamEntryID == EntryId
                            && c.comID > LastId
                            select c
                            ).ToList();

                return View("DisplayComments", comments);
            }
        }

        return View("CommentError", "Unable to post comment.");
    }
```

When everything is fine and the action returns `return View("DisplayComments", comments);` the `$.post()` success function is triggered. But, When the action returns `return View("CommentError", "Unable to post comment.");` The `$.post()` ajax fails. I don't understand why the `$.post()` cares which view I'm returning.

Here's my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#comments").ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
            alert("Error requesting page " + settings.url);
        });

        $("button#submitComment").click(function () {

            var commentList = $("#comments");

            var lastId = $(".comment h4").last().attr("id");
            var commentData = "EntryId=" + $("input#EntryID").val()
                                + "&Comment=" + $("textarea#Comment").val()
                                + "&LastId=" + lastId;

            $.post(
                "/find/Comments/Comments",
                commentData,
                function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                    alert(data);
                    if ($(data).filter(".error").length > 0) {
                        error = $(data);
                        $(this).after(error);
                    }
                    else {
                        newComments = $(data);
                        newComments.filter(".comment").css('display', 'none');
                        alert(newComments);
                        commentList.append(newComments);

                        $(".comment").each(function () {
                            $(this).slideDown("fast")
                        });

                        $("#Comment").attr("value", "");
                    }
                }
            );

        });
    });

</script>
```

What about this could cause the ajax to fail?

Here's what the two views look like:

#### View("DisplayComments", comments); (works)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<Genesis.Domain.Entities.Comments>>" %>

<% foreach (var item in Model) %>
<% { %>
    <div class="comment" style="background:#eee; border:1px solid gray; padding:10px 10px 0 10px; margin-bottom:20px;">
        <h4 id="<%:item.comID %>"><%: item.Member.ScreenName%> commented on <%: String.Format("{0:f}", item.Date)%></h4>
        <p>
        <%: item.Comment%>
        </p>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

#### View("CommentError", "Unable to post comment."); (does not work)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<div class="error">
<%:Model%>
</div>
```

What about this could cause the ajax post to fail?

Comment: Did you try to see what was the response? You can try Firebug to see the response.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise what do you mean by *it fails*? What does FireBug says about the AJAX request? What is the server responding? Request, response, status code, ...? Using FireBug should be your first reflex when an AJAX call fails before posting your question here.

Comment: What do you mean by response? The views both return html. when the post is successfull the success function of $.post() excutes correctly. When the CommentError view is returned, the .ajaxError() event is triggered.

Comment: this might help you to create the ajax comment poster: http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `ajaxError` function is triggered this strongly indicates that your controller action returns a status code different than 200, probably 500 which is a strong indication that your controller action throws an exception before ever reaching the last line and be able to return a view.

So here are the steps to do:

1. Use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/)
2. Look at what your server sends as response to the AJAX request
3. Analyze the response status code and the response contents

Alternative approach:

1. Put a breakpoint in your controller action
2. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
3. When the controller action is hit step through your code
4. Observe exactly what happens

Remark: I would very strongly recommend you properly encoding your AJAX input. So instead of:

```
var commentData = "EntryId=" + $("input#EntryID").val()
                            + "&Comment=" + $("textarea#Comment").val()
                            + "&LastId=" + lastId;
```

you definitely should:

```
var commentData = $.param({
    EntryId: $("input#EntryID").val(),
    Comment: $("textarea#Comment").val(),
    LastId: lastId
});
```

Note that everytime you use the `+`, `&` and `=` signs when dealing with querystring parameters (no matter what language you are using) you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I have firebug... how do I look at the server's response with it? I've only ever used it to browse the DOM

Comment: I have put breakpoints in my action already. I have also run with F5. no exceptions or server error. It is reaching the return View etc...

Comment: I haven't used `$.param()`before. I'll try it. But, isn't `$.param()` just return a string anyway? Why wouldn't i want to just create the string if I know how to do it?

Comment: @quakkels, in FireBug look at the Console tab. When an AJAX request is sent it will appear there. Once it appears click on the `+` sign to develop. Now look at the response HTML and status code.

Comment: @quakkels, as far as $.param is concerned this will URL encode your query string parameters. Suppose that in the textarea a user enters the following comment: `I will crap &LastId=your site`. You see: he uses `&` and `=`: If you don't encode those it will totally mess your controller action and what you receive there. As you are using string concatenations to build your query string the following url will be used: `?EntryId=123&Comment=I will crap &LastId=your site&LastId=456`. See the problem here?

Comment: @Darin - Sweet... now I know its a 500 error. Gotta figure out why it's 500.

Comment: @Darin - About `$.param()`... I hadn't thought of that :-)

Comment: @quakkels, now you know it is a 500 error, look at the Response tab. You will see the exact HTML response sent by the server. Probably a YSOD (yellow screen of death)

Comment: @Darin - sweet... now I have something to go on... Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'CommentError' or its master was not found.

Comment: Thanks... these techniques are brand new to me and they really are usefull... obviously :-)

Comment: @quakkels, cool, now all that's left is to add the view: `~/Views/Comments/CommentError.ascx` :-)

Comment: Yeah... it actually is there already. but for some reason it's not connecting when called. idk why yet. probably a silly typo somewhere. It might be fodder for another question here.

Comment: If anyone is interested in why the 500 error was happening, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522409/why-is-my-asp-net-action-looking-for-the-wrong-view