# Why is my ASP.NET Action looking for the wrong View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a simple action:

```
    public ActionResult CommentError(string error)
    {
        return View(error);
    }
```

I have a simple partial view called CommentError.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<String>" %>

<%: Model %>
```

When I browse to the view directy by going to `myurl.com/find/Comments/CommentError` the view displays fine... no errors.

But, when I go to `myurl.com/find/Comments/CommentError?error=SomeErrorString`, instead of binding the querystring to `string error`, it looks for a view called `SomeErrorString.ascx`.

Why is this happening?

**Edit**
Note, i do have a custom global.asax as indicated by the paths I'm using (/find/Comments/CommentError ::: /find/{controler}/{action})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned, MVC is looking for a view named the same as the string parameter.  To avoid this, you need to cast it to an object...

```
public ActionResult CommentError(string error)
{
    return View((object)error);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You generally should avoid the `Model` object you pass to the `View()` helper being of type `string`. This is the cause of your error.

MVC is looking for a `View` *named* what your string parameter is. Because that's what the best matching overload of `View()` is: the `View(string)` overload uses the `string` parameter as the name of the view to load.

You should encapsulate your Model data (the string) in a custom type, or pass that info via the `ViewData` collection instead.

Comment: ... ViewData? And forgo strongly typed views? really?

Comment: @quakkels: As a second option if the developer chooses not to go the first suggested route, a custom Model.

Comment: @David - I mentioned a custom Model object. quakkels was too busy knee-jerking to see that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer (just for education) you could just invoke a different overload of View()

```
return View("CommentError", null, error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!